# Checking for typeof !== 'object' breaks exports in a file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a utils.js file. In it are a number of functions, which at the end of the file I export with:

```
exports.findOtherOccurrenceInList = findOtherOccurrenceInList;
exports.cloneList = cloneList;
exports.isNullOrUndef = isNullOrUndef;
exports.isNullOrEmpty = isNullOrEmpty;
exports.cloneObject = cloneObject;
```

My problem is related to the "cloneObject" function. The source of this function is:

```
function cloneObject(objToClone) {
  if (typeof objToClone !== 'string') {
    return objToClone;
  }
  if (isNullOrUndef(objToClone)) {
    return objToClone;
  }

  let temp = objToClone.constructor();

  for (let key in objToClone) {
    temp[key] = cloneObject(objToClone[key]);
  }

  return temp;
}
```

I then include utils.js, in a .vue file via a destructuring assignment. This works without any problems.

However, as soon as I change the first line of the function from

```
 if (typeof objToClone !== 'string') {
```

into

```
 if (typeof objToClone !== 'object') {
```

all of the exports seem to break, as immediately a number of warnings are generated:

```
warning  in <some code>

"export 'cloneList' was not found in '@/utils/utils'

warning  in <some code>

"export 'isNullOrEmpty' was not found in '@/utils/utils'

warning  in <some code>

"export 'findOtherOccurrenceInList' was not found in '@/utils/utils'
```

etcetera.

As soon as I change the first line back to a check on 'string' everything is working again, and the warnings disappear.
(And I have tried exporting the functions with module.exports, but that doesn't make any difference...)

What could be causing this weird behaviour??

Comment: `typeof null === "object"; // true`

Comment: How are you importing the files?

Comment: What tool is generating these warnings?

Comment: Yeah, the null check should be before the object check. And it was that way, before I started moving code around a bit to see why the exports started to break. I have reverted it back to this situation, and the warnings remain.

Comment: I am importing the file and its functions at the start of the script-block of a .vue component file. E.g. like:

      import { findOtherOccurrenceInList, cloneList } from '@/utils/utils';

The warnings are generated on the command-line of the localhost frontend (Vue) server, which I have started via npm.